# Send encrypted and signed email using C#

Tags: c#, email, encryption, mime, digital-signature

I want to send an encrypted and signed mail without using any third-party API.
If I send only the alternate view with the signature, Windows Mail can validate it. If I send only with alternate view with encrypted data, Windows Mail can decipher it. But if I send both, Windows Mail gets 2 attachements. If I sign the `encryptedBytes` and add those signed bytes to the alternative view it only validates the signature and the message is empty.
Any idea?

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress(lblMail.Text);
message.Subject = txtSubject.Text;

string body = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7Bit\r\n\r\n" + structForm();

byte[] messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(messageData);
EnvelopedCms envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms(content);

message.To.Add(new MailAddress(provMail));

CmsRecipient recipient = new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, this.certificate);
envelopedCms.Encrypt(recipient);

byte[] encryptedBytes = envelopedCms.Encode();

SignedCms Cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(encryptedBytes));
CmsSigner Signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, new X509Certificate2(@"c:\serv.pfx","123"));

Cms.ComputeSignature(Signer);
byte[] SignedBytes = Cms.Encode();

MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes);
AlternateView encryptedView = new AlternateView(encryptedStream, "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed--data;name=smime.p7m");
message.AlternateViews.Add(encryptedView);
MemoryStream signedStream = new MemoryStream(SignedBytes);
AlternateView signedView = new AlternateView(signedStream, "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data;name=sig.p7m");
message.AlternateViews.Add(signedView);


System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailaddress@xpto.com", "XXXXXX");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.xpto.com");

client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;

client.Send(message);

Label2.Text = "Assinado e cifrado!";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should sign first, then encrypt.

While the original CMS and S/MIME specifications allow you to do the operations in either order, later work pointed out that signing a document that you can't read is a really bad idea. The signature should be over the plain-text.

---

The resulting MIME message should only have a single part, which should be S/MIME enveloped-data. Your message has two parts, and the encrypted part is mis-labeled with a signed-data content-type. Create and sign the `SignedCms` object. Encode it, and use the encoded value as the content of an `EnvelopedCms` object. Encrypt that, and use its encoded value as the content of your `MailMessage`, with a content type of "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data".

Comment: So I did put the signature being done before the encryption. However, it is still the same effect. If I send only the signature + encryption it doesn't work well

Comment: I believe you saying to do something like this? http://pastebin.com/g1q6fkJL (sorry.. comments do not take code...)
I tried this way and, after the message, I get scrumbled characters...